# How can I stream live TV from Windows Media Center to another computer?

Tags: windows-7, streaming, windows-media-center

How can I watch the live TV stream from my desktop computer on my laptop?

I am using Windows 7 Ultimate on both a desktop PC and a laptop.  Both are connected on the same LAN and workgroup via 54Mbps wi-fi.  The desktop has an internal TV card with a carefully positioned aerial due to being in a low reception area.  Getting a USB TV dongle isn't an option due to the lack of reception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this article : ["Streaming Live TV"](http://blog.tmcnet.com/blog/tom-keating/voip/streaming-live-tv.asp) , for how to do that using [VideoLAN](http://www.videolan.org/).

Answer (score 4):

I finally found a working solution to this and thought I'd post it for anyone looking.  Although it uses third party software (free) and not Windows Media Center, as per my question, it still does the job.

[**ProgDVB**](http://www.progdvb.com/) seems to do the trick.  The software is installed on both the "server" which has the TV card and the "client", say a wirelessly connected laptop for example.

You configure the ProgDVB Media Server(Home) module on the "server" within ProgDVB ...

[image]
... and then enable and configure the Prog Media Client device on the "client".

[image]

You can then view and control progDVB on the laptop as though you were using it on the computer with the TV card.  Works an absolute treat, even over wireless - access to all channels.

Answer (score 2):

You could try [Mediaportal](http://www.team-mediaportal.com/mediaportal-features/television). It works really well, is completely free, and open source.

- Add guide data from a variety of sources like DVB signal, web (via
  XMLTV) or Clickfinder (Germany)
- Define as many channel groups as you wish, such as Favorites, News,
  Sports, Music, Movies
- Change channel groups
- Search programs by name, genre or channel
- View all upcoming airings of your favorite shows
- Select the IMDB (Internet Movie Database) option for more movie
  details and images

> If you have more than one PC in your home, you no longer have to
>   install a TV card into every one. Simply place your TV card(s) in one
>   PC and install MediaPortal with the "Dedicated TV server" option.
>   Then, on all your other PCs install the "MediaPortal client" option to
>   receive live, or recorded TV, and TV guide data from your server.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this:
http://www.overclock.net/htpc/570165-windows-7-live-tv-lan-streaming.html